# Finding the index of certain strings in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, date-and-time

I'm actually using a dataset of much greater dimensions and length but I simplified my problem of string patterns in order to ask this question.

```
dates = {"2018-01-01 22:00:00", "2018-01-01 22:30:00", "2018-01-01 23:00:00", "2018-01-01 23:30:00", "2018-01-02 00:00:00", "2018-01-02 00:30:00", 
 "2018-01-02 01:00:00", "2018-01-02 01:30:00", "2018-01-02 02:00:00", "2018-01-02 02:30:00", "2018-01-02 03:00:00", "2018-01-02 03:30:00", 
 "2018-01-02 04:00:00", "2018-01-02 04:30:00", "2018-01-02 05:00:00", "2018-01-02 05:30:00", "2018-01-02 06:00:00", "2018-01-02 06:30:00", 
 "2018-01-02 07:00:00", "2018-01-02 07:30:00", "2018-01-02 08:00:00", "2018-01-02 08:30:00", "2018-01-02 09:00:00", "2018-01-02 09:30:00", 
 "2018-01-02 10:00:00", "2018-01-02 10:30:00", "2018-01-02 11:00:00", "2018-01-02 11:30:00", "2018-01-02 12:00:00", "2018-01-02 12:30:00", 
 "2018-01-02 13:00:00", "2018-01-02 13:30:00", "2018-01-02 14:00:00", "2018-01-02 14:30:00", "2018-01-02 15:00:00", "2018-01-02 15:30:00", 
 "2018-01-02 16:00:00", "2018-01-02 16:30:00", "2018-01-02 17:00:00", "2018-01-02 17:30:00", "2018-01-02 18:00:00", "2018-01-02 18:30:00", 
 "2018-01-02 19:00:00", "2018-01-02 19:30:00", "2018-01-02 20:00:00", "2018-01-02 20:30:00", "2018-01-02 21:00:00", "2018-01-02 21:30:00", 
 "2018-01-02 22:00:00", "2018-01-02 22:30:00", "2018-01-02 23:00:00", "2018-01-02 23:30:00", "2018-01-03 00:00:00", "2018-01-03 00:30:00", 
 "2018-01-03 01:00:00", "2018-01-03 01:30:00"}
```

Assuming I have the above list of dates, I'm trying to find the index of the dates matching the below string pattern.

```
patt = ___ ~~ "23:30:00"
```

Both `Positions` nor `Cases` return empty with my pattern. `StringCases` does but the output is a bit unwieldily.

```
StringCases[dates, patt]
```

Which means I have to do something like below to get the indexes I need.

```
Select[
   PositionIndex[
    StringCases[ dates , patt ]
    ], 
   Length@# < 2 &
   ] // Values // Flatten

(* Returns *)
{4, 52}
```

Does anyone know of a way to directly get the index of a string pattern with `Position`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Pick[Range @ Length @ dates, StringMatchQ[patt] @ dates]
```

> {4, 52}

```
Pick[Range @ Length @ dates, StringEndsQ["23:30:00"] @ dates]
```

> {4, 52}

```
Flatten @ Position[_String?(StringMatchQ[patt])] @ dates
```

> ```
> {4, 52}
> ```

```
Flatten @ Position[_String?(StringEndsQ["23:30:00"])] @ dates
```

> ```
> {4, 52}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
patt = __ ~~ "23:30:00"
pos1 = Position[dates, x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, patt]]
```

> {{4}, {52}}

To extract these values:

```
Extract[dates, pos1]
```

---

Since dates and times are involved, try the following:

```
Position[dates, x_String /; TimeObject[x] == TimeObject["23:30:00"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Position[StringMatchQ[dates, ___ ~~ "23:30:00"], True]
```

Flatten it if you want literally just a list of integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
p = Position[Last @* StringSplit /@ dates, "23:30:00"]
```

{{4}, {52}}

```
Extract[dates, p]
```

{"2018-01-01 23:30:00", "2018-01-02 23:30:00"}